# Use Robolectrics with Mockito to mock/stub function call making http request, but it doesn't work

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito, robolectric

I am using [Robolectrics](http://robolectric.org) and [Mockito](http://mockito.org) to unit test android project, I mock a method which makes http request to backend.

The actual class of http client:

```
public class MyHttpClient {
 ...
 public int sendDataToBackend(Object data) {
    return doHttpRequest(data);
 }

 private int doHttpRequest() {
    System.out.println("start http request ...");
    ...
    return responseCode;
 }
}
```

The above `MyHttpClient` class is used in `MyService` class:

```
public class MyService {
 ...
 public void notifyBackend(Object data) {
   MyHttpClient client = new MyHttpClient();
   int responseCode = client.sendDataToBackend(data);
   ...
 }
}
```

I unit test `MyService`:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
  @Mock
  private MyHttpClient client;

  @InjectMocks
  private MyService service;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    client = new MyHttpClient();
    service = new MyService();
  }

  @Test
  public void testNotifyBackend() {
    Object data = generateData();
    //stub method call
    when(client.sendDataToBackend(data)).thenReturn(200);

    service.notifyBackend(data);
  }
}
```

I run my above unit test, I expected that the `sendDataToBackend()` function body in `MyHttpClient` class wouldn't be executed, because we have mocked/stub the function to return 200, however I still see the `System.out.print()` message:

```
start http request ...
```

from `MyHttpClient#doHttpRequest()` , why?

(And my test is failed because it tries to do real http request)

**====== UPDATE =======**

Besides, I also think I shouldn't do `client = new MyHttpClient` in `setUp()`, because `client` should have been mocked, but when I tried:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
  service = new MyService();
}
```

I got **NullPointerException** in :

`when(client.sendDataToBackend(data)).thenReturn(200);`,

that's the reason why I add `client = new MyHttpClient` in `setUp()`. I also want to ask why I got **NullPointerException**, if the `client` is mocked?

Comment: With the provided snippet, `MyService` does even use `MyHttpClient`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Mureinik, what do you mean ? `MyService#notifyBackend()` is using MyHttpClient, why you say it doesn't use http client class?

Comment: Well it does now, after the question was edited...

Comment: Is it really mocked? Did you add the MockitoJUnitRunner, as it's missing from your test class...

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz, I am using `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)` , because I am using Android test framework Robolectrics, but on internet there are tutorials of using Robolectrics with Mockito, there, they didn't use the MockitoJunitRunner, but using the robolectrics runner. For exapmle, here http://sdudzin.blogspot.fi/2011/01/easy-unit-testing-for-android.html

Comment: In your example, all the mocking is done via `(Mockito.)mock( ... .class );` calls. Are you sure that the `RobolectricTestRunner` will actually use the `@Mock` annotation? If not, you could simply add `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );` at the beginning of your `@before` Method.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz , thanks, at least I don't get any exception now, but sendDataToBackend() function is actually calling from another thread asynchrously, I posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593865/user-mockito-to-unit-test-a-function-doing-async-task-in-my-case , could you please take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating the client in the service, provide it through the constructor:

```
class MyService {
   final MyHttpClient client;
   MyService(MyHttpClient client) { this.client = client; }
}
```

Then, in your test, feed it the mocked client. It's as simple as that.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
  @Mock
  private MyHttpClient client;

  private MyService service;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    service = new MyService(client);
  }
  ....    
}
```

Comment: It is injected using `@InjectMocks`. Isn't that enough?

Comment: No, it isn't injected. `MyService` creates a new client instance every time `notifyBackend`is called. `@InjectMocks` requires a constructor, property or field to manage injection.

Comment: Could you provide an alternative way without passing MyHttpClient to the constructor of MyService? I mean can we solve the problem without changing these two classes?

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
  service = new MyService();
}
```

You've mocked it, right. But then you're overwriting that instance by assigning `client` a new instance of `MyHttpClient`.

Comment: I did it, but then I got NullPointerException in this line `when(client.sendDataToBackend(data)).thenReturn(200);`