# User Mockito to unit test a function doing async task in my case

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

In my **Android** project, I have a class extends [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html):

```
public class MyHandlerThread extends HandlerThreads {
   private Handler mHandler;
   …
   public void doAsyncTask(MyAsyncTask task) {
        mHandler = new Handler(this.getLooper());
        mHandler.post(task);
    }
}
```

The above function's parameter type `MyAsyncTask` is a class extends `Runnable`:

```
public abstract class MyAsyncTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doTask();
    }

    public abstract void doTask();
}
```

I have a `MyWorker` class which has a function uses `MyHandlerThread` class:

```
public class MyWorker {

  public void work() {
      MyHandlerThread handlerThread = new MyHandlerThread();
      handlerThread.start();
      handlerThread.doAsyncTask(new MyAsyncTask() {
           @Override
           doTask() {
               int responseCode = sendDataToServer();
           }
      });
  }
}
```

I want to use [Mockito](http://mockito.org) to unit test the `work()` function in `MyWorker` class (e.g. check the server `responseCode`). How to do it in Mockito?

Answer (score 0):

WHAT do you want to test? `MyWorker`? `MyHandlerThread`? the anonymous `MyAsyncTask`? All toegether? Probably a bad idea, especially if the anonymous `MyAsyncTask` relies on an actual server response (which would prevent this from being a good unit test, since you are testing a whole system then). So, I would split the whole thing into parts and test all these parts seperately. If you have done so, then you can check multiple parts toegether against a real server with an integration tests.

To test the MyHandlerThread, you could for example introduce a HandlerFactory, mock that and thus ensure that the handler was called correctly.

```
public class MyHandlerThread extends HandlerThreads {
   private HandlerFactory handlerFactory; // <- Add setter
   …
   public void doAsyncTask(MyAsyncTask task) {
        Handler mHandler = handlerFactory.createHandler(this.getLooper());
        mHandler.post(task);
    }
}
```

Easily testable unit. `MyAsyncTask` is short and abstract, honestly, I wouldn't test that. Not much to gain there, since it doesn't actually do much.  And the `MyWorker` ? Depends, but you could, for example, add a getter/setter for the `MyHandlerThread`, allowing you to mock that. Extracting your anonymous class into a real one would probably allow you to test that one, too, independent of the others.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point but seems you don't get my question. To clarify (though I think I also mentioned in my question), I want to have a unit test class for MyWorker class, and I want to test the  `work()` function in that class. I know I shouldn't test the whole system waiting for server response, that is the reason why I said I use mockito, I want to mock this part, my question is how to do it? How to use mockito to test `work()` function without do real server request?

Comment: As I already said, you can either use a getter/setter for the `MyHandlerThread` or also a factory pattern, both possibilties would allow you to mock and test it. Also you could move the new MyAsyncTask into it's own class (or at least method) to be able to test that on itself.