# How to test a Firebase task on Android?

Tags: android, asynchronous, firebase, junit, mockito

Now I am trying to test it using JUnit4, but I am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
    Must not be called on the main application thread

at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzab.zzhj(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzab.zzate(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(Unknown Source)
at com.example.tasks.GetUserProfileTest.then(GetUserProfileTest.java:18)
    <27 internal calls>

Process finished with exit code 255
```

I've created a [Continuation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Continuation) task that performs an operation on [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/).

```
public class GetUserProfile implements Continuation<String, Task<Profile>>,
        ValueEventListener {

    private TaskCompletionSource<Profile> mTaskCompletionSource;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    public GetUserProfile() {
        mTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        mDatabase.removeEventListener(this);
        mTaskCompletionSource.setException(databaseError.toException());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        mDatabase.removeEventListener(this);
        mTaskCompletionSource.setResult(dataSnapshot.getValue(Profile.class));
    }

    @Override
    public Task<Profile> then(Task<String> task) {
        mDatabase.child(task.getResult()).addValueEventListener(this);
        return mTaskCompletionSource.getTask();
    }
}
```

and unit test for it:

```
public class GetUserProfileTest {
    @Test
    public void then() throws Exception {
        Task<Profile> task = Tasks.<String>forResult("17354686546")
            .continueWithTask(new GetUserProfile());

        try {
            Profile profile = Tasks.await(task);
            assertEquals(profile.getEmail(), "john.connor@email.com");
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            fail(e.getMessage());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way of testing tasks without using [handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593865/user-mockito-to-unit-test-a-function-doing-async-task-in-my-case) or [`CountDownLatch`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)?

Comment: Exactly which line is causing the error, and what is its full stack trace?

Comment: `Tasks.await` because it is blocking the main thread. I know it could be done using `CountDownLatch`, but I was hopping to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: I would just call the `then` method on the Continuation directly.  Also, to be a true unit test, I would mock the database altogether and just check that it was consulted correctly.  But if a unit test really must test threading (it's better if they don't), CDL is the way to go.

Comment: @DougStevenson, view and presenter tests are using mocked data, but testing the communication with Firebase is also one of the project requirements. Invoking `then` directly worked perfectly, for both `tcs.setResult` and `tcs.setException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class GetUserProfileTest {
    @Test
    public void then() throws Exception {
        try {
            Task<String> previousTask = Tasks.forResult("17354686546");
            GetUserProfile continuation = new GetUserProfile();
            Profile profile = continuation
                    .then(previousTask)
                    .getResult();

            assertEquals(profile.getEmail(), "john.connor@email.com");
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            fail(e.getMessage());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The above testing solution throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete